Custom Ramp up in LRE for batch vusers
Is it possible to give custom ramp up in LRE for a single group to a batch of vusers.
For eg.
We have a batch of 17 users which needs to start every 20 seconds. We need to configure for every batch of 17 vusers, 1 user ramps up at every 10 seconds.
So,If we have total of 170 vusers there are 10 batches in which each batch will have a custom ramp up time.
I tried to insert one action with start 1 every 10 seconds in the scheduler after starting 17 users every 20 seconds but it adds the vuser count and not solves the purpose. Please let me know any other options available to setup up similar scenario

Yes. This is possible.  This is covered in training, which lets us know that you have been pressed into this role without training nor a mentor.
You should insist that your managers provide you training and a mentor or your path to value is all but certain to take years.
